# Delete Apps from Play Store

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I created a sample app in my developer account at play store and published it. Just for showing how it works. But now I can't delete the app only "repealed publication". Is there a way to delete my own apps in play store?

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is already one delete button available on play store account

Answer (score 2):

Sing in with your account and then press on unpublish .... Your app will be removed from play store

Answer (score 0):

unpublish your app and it will be removed.